# How to disable MDM for infrared on LG S3

Tags: android, mdm, infrared, lg

I'm trying to send an infraRed pattern from my application on an LG G3.
Apparently, LG doesn't use the existing `ConsumerIrManager` so I've added LG's own QRemoteSDK to my project.

But calling

> mIR.sendIRPattern((int)frequency, timePattern);

returns an error `ResultCode.IR_PORT_DISABLED`.  This error is documented as

> IR features can be managed by Mobile Device Management (MDM). If
>   Mobile Device Management is enabled, IR functionality cannot be used.
>   In that case, QRemote APIs will return ResultCode.IR_PORT_DISABLED and
>   shows the toast popup with the warning "Remote control is unavailable
>   by server policy."

MDM is new to me. Is this MDM somehow under my control? How can I disable this?

Note that

- the LG remote application *does* work
- this is a personal phone, not linked to a company, used in-home trying to control our TV
- it has no SIM-card for the moment

Comment: Same problem here.  Do you find a workaround?

Comment: @Luiz LG states that IR SDK is not supported on LG G3 s http://developer.lge.com/community/forums/RetrieveForumContent.dev?detailContsId=FC27190028&sMenuId=55&contsTypeCode=QUE&prodTypeCode=MOBILE   I'm sceptical/surprised though since the LG remote application does work

Comment: That is akward. I tried in my LG G2 Mini and the LG remote application works fine too but the SDK does not work.

Comment: @Luiz and is your LG G2 Mini in the list of supported devices as given here http://developer.lge.com/resource/mobile/RetrieveOverview.dev?categoryTypeCode=ANRS#supporteddev ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. :/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is right answer for you, (because my phone is Samsung) but I think it is worth a try.

Setting -> Security -> Device administration -> Deactivate Android device manager.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, it didn't help.